# Novel where Earth is about to advance to the next level but humanity isn't ready, so god sends humans to other worlds but forgets one person

Tags: story-identification

Earth is about to level up to the next level, but humanity is not ready. In order for humanity to not be decimated by monsters, god sends humanity to other worlds to prepare them, but he forgets one person.

The protagonist escapes god's perception but is later found out. In order for him to survive god sends an angel to teach him martial arts.

The time is stopped, and he spends 1000 years training all alone, while the other humans spent 10 years on other worlds to level up and learn skills.

Later on, humanity is brought back, and the evolution of Earth begins.

Comment: Can you tell us when you read this (about what year), was it current then or from an earlier decade? Can you remember any character names, the name of the author, anything about the cover of the book? The more information you can give us the better we can help, thanks :)

Comment: i read it a couple a months ago, i think it a recent one ( chinese or japanese probably don't really remember) i read it on a site for novels, the gender i thinck it is actione, adventure and harem, as for the characters the mc he is in college and has the power to go unnoticed therfore god doesn't see him the first time, and he gets left behind, so the earth gets stopped for 10 years that is the period for the other humans to learn skills in the other worlds

Comment: but for the mc someting happens and hi spends 1000 years  he and the animals and vegetation dont age, and time ends (10 years for the others and 1000 for the mc) all the humans get transported back to earth.when they get back the earth evolution begins and all the animals get transformed into monsters and dungeons appear, so now the people gets their skills reseted to lv 1 , one of the female mc uses magic of tunder or lighting.

Comment: never mind i found it - Everyone Else is a Returnee

Comment: Don't go away! You can post your own answer to your own question, you'd be amazed how often people will go to ask a story identification question, only to have that question pop up before they ask. If you could provide an answer that would be great :)

Comment: The trope of "humans removed from earth" has shown up in at least two other works I can think of. In the Skolian saga by Catherine Asaro, some (but not all) humans were removed from Earth and settled on another world thousands of years ago. They have now developed the Skolian Empire. And in A Choice of Gods by Clifford D Simak, nearly all of humanity is resettled on a distant planet, while the few remaining on Earth develop a different society entirely.

Answer (score 18):

### [Everyone Else is a Returnee](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/everyone-else-is-a-returnee/)

> Earth is changing. The concentration of mana has reached a level where the world is about to be ‘activated’. In order to provide humanity a chance, heaven implements a plan to have humanity level up. Yu Ilhan, our MC, was left out while every single human on Earth was transported to other worlds. After experiencing solitude for untold years, everyone is back, and he can’t use mana. Join Ilhan in this action-packed adventure filled with adrenaline, cheap attacks, comedy, references for days, desperate noonas, and more!
> <sub>Translated synopsis by /u/MMatosz on reddit, [taken from this link](https://kobatochan.com/korean-novels/everyone-else-is-a-returnee/)</sub>

[image: English Cover for the book] [image: Korean Cover for the book]

Comment: Can you add some more details to what makes them similar, I'm aware you know for a fact that this is it, but other users who may think they're looking for the same book may benefit from extra details.